# React Modal not working in Header Component

Tags: reactjs, react-modal

I have a Login component in my header(bootstrap) which needs to open a Modal when I click. I am using the Modal from react-modal (npm package).
Even though I am not getting an error the popup won't open.

```
this.state={
    openModal:false
}

closeModal=()=>{
    this.setState({openModal:false})
}

 handleOnClick=()=>{
     this.setState({openModal:true}
 }
```

Header Component

```
` <ul className="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li onClick={this.handleOnClick()}><a href="#">
                    <Modal 
                        isOpen={this.state.openModal}
                        onRequestClose={this.closeModal}
                        style={customStyles}
                        contentLabel="Example Modal"
                    >
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span></Modal> Sign Up</a></li>

                    <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Login</a></li>
                </ul>`
```

Comment: add the code where you are trying to open the modal

Comment: @aravind_reddy I have added the code where I am trying  to open the modal

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove the brackets `()` from the call. What you give to `onClick` is the function to call, not the code to run like in other frameworks like Angular.

So, that'll be `onClick={this.handleOnClick}`

Answer (score 0):

This is the working code.

```
   <ul className="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                            <li  onClick={this.handleOnClick}><a href="#">
                            <Modal 
                                isOpen={this.state.openModal}
                                onRequestClose={this.closeModal}
                                style={customStyles}
                                content

                            ><LoginComponent />
                        </Modal> Login</a></li>
```